# What is the best way to hide Crashlytics key?

Tags: android, crashlytics

I put my crashlytics key in `xml` and I got this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug'.
>
> > Crashlytics Developer Tools error.

The following is my intended code in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
    android:value="@string/crashlytics_key" />
```

What is the best way to hide it?

Comment: Why are you trying to hide keys from a repository? If you can't trust the developers who have access to your code, you're going to have a lot bigger problems than just them having the key. And if you are worried about a disgruntled employee in the future, you can just refresh the API key as needed.

Comment: it's a public repo

Comment: Ah, makes sense.  Why not just have a dummy key on the repo then (and clarify it in the readme)?

Comment: but, that means every time I want to commit, I need to remember myself to replace my api key with the dummy one. If I put it in another file, I can just put that file in `.gitignore` and I can continue developing as usual.

Comment: This should work then: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables.html -- You can pull the variable from a file like local.properies (with Groovy) that isn't commited and then inject it into the manifest

Comment: Added an answer with some example code to get you started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your API key in local.properties.

```
crashlytics.key=api_key_here
```

In your build.gradle, add this Groovy method:

```
def getLocalProperty(String propertyName) {
    def propsFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (propsFile.exists()) {
        def props = new Properties()
        props.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile))
        return props[propertyName]
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```

And then add a manifest placeholder, for example:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [crashlytics:getLocalProperty("crashlytics.key")]
    }
}
```

In your manifest, you can now access the API key as an injected variable with the following syntax:

```
${crashlytics}
```

You might need to tweak this code to get it to work for your needs, but this should be enough to get you started. And make sure to add local.properties to your .gitignore (if it isn't already!) Hope that helps.

Comment: not secure i have try this but after i decompile apk api_key is visiable in code site

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to do it in a such complex way as in accepted answer.

According to [the official docs](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/settings/working-in-teams.html#android-projects), you can simply remove your API key from Manifest and put to `fabric.properties` file, where your secret already lies in a next form:

```
apiKey=fabric_api_key
apiSecret=fabric_api_secret
```

And that is it. Fabric plugin (or Gradle task) will automatically do all the needed work inside the hood.

P.s. Don't forget to keep your `fabric.properties` file outside of your Version Control System

Answer (score 1):

Well placing both keys to `fabric.properties` didn't work for me and fabric could not found api key there and wanted, me to put it in Manifest. Then I discovered this solution:

Place `io.fabric.ApiKey=676897890789790...` 
to your `local.properties`

To AndroidManifest add this:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="@string/fabric_api_key" />
```

Then in app module `build.gradle`

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
def fabricApiKey = properties.getProperty('io.fabric.ApiKey')
if (fabricApiKey == null) fabricApiKey = "Place io.fabric.ApiKey to local.properties"
```

then in defaultConfig closure:

```
defaultConfig {
   .....
         resValue "string", "fabric_api_key", fabricApiKey
    }
```

This way you can hide also google maps key from source control for open source projects and still keep application buildable for continuous integration or people wanting to try it out...