# Best practice for using Fabric/Crashlytics with open-source app?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have an iOS app that I'm about to open source. I don't want to include my key and secret in the Run Script code when the the app is live for everyone to look at, fork, download etc. for obvious reasons.

What is the best way to still use Fabric/Crashlytics but also keep those keys secure so that only those who can deploy the app have access to those credentials?

Comment: What about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47880326/creating-dummy-fabric-api-keys-for-an-open-source-project

Comment: Only sort of helpful. Android-related post...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way:

1 - Store fabric keys in a local file.

```
<apiKey>
<secretKey>
```

2 - In your cocoa pods run script phase (under Build Phases in Xcode), have your script grab the api key and secret key from the local file.

```
apiKey=$(sed -n '1p' < localFile.txt)
secretKey=$(sed -n '2p' < localFile.txt)
```

3 - Use `PlistBuddy` in the cocoa pods run script phase to set the API Key into your `Info.plist` file. Something like this:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :Fabric:APIKey string $apiKey" $(PROJECT_DIR)/Info.plist
```

4 - Call the cocoa pods `run` command.

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" $apiKey $secretKey
```

Edit: full script

```
apiKey=$(sed -n '1p' < localFile.txt)
secretKey=$(sed -n '2p' < localFile.txt)

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :Fabric:APIKey string $apiKey" $(PROJECT_DIR)/Info.plist

"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" $apiKey $secretKey
```

**NOTE** -
`$(PROJECT_DIR)/Info.plist` may not be the correct path for your particular project.

Comment: Is this all in one Run Script?

Comment: Yes. There should already be a run script with the cocoa pods `run` command. Edit that run script with the code above (may need some slight tweaking).

Comment: Thanks, working on that now. Seeing what needs tweaking

Comment: This didn't work for me and the issue originates from the path to `Info.plist`, I found a solution and posted another answer.

Comment: getting error:- erminating app due to uncaught exception 'FABException', reason: '[Fabric] Value of Info.plist key "Fabric" must be a NSDictionary.'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: I found I needed to tweak your script a little to incorporate the ${PROJECT_NAME} and remove `string` from the PlistBuddy args: ```apiKey=$(sed -n '1p' < localFile.txt)
secretKey=$(sed -n '2p' < localFile.txt)
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :Fabric:APIKey $apiKey" ${PROJECT_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/Info.plist

"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" $apiKey $secretKey```

Answer (score 0):

Jake's answer didn't work for me. Apparently `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Info.plist` returns an incorrect path.

But here's a working example for a project that uses both Fabric and Google sign in. (This works perfectly in Xcode 9 as of July 2018)

```
FabricApiKey=$(sed -n '2p' < app_config.txt)
FabricSecretKey=$(sed -n '4p' < app_config.txt)
GoogleReversedClientId=$(sed -n '6p' < app_config.txt)

INFO_PLIST="$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :Fabric:APIKey $FabricApiKey" "$INFO_PLIST"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleURLTypes:0:CFBundleURLSchemes:0 $GoogleReversedClientId" "$INFO_PLIST"

"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" $FabricApiKey $FabricSecretKey
```

and here's the structure of `app_config.txt` file that must be present at the project root:

```
FabricApiKey:
your_key_here
FabricSecretKey:
your_secret_here
GoogleReversedClientId:
google_reversed_client_id_here
```

Comment: getting error :- Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FABException', reason: '[Fabric] Value of Info.plist key "Fabric" must be a NSDictionary.'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 0):

Excellent post by @Jake - thank-you! This is my variation which checks for the existence of the secrets file, and uses some environment variables provided by Xcode 9.4.

```
#1/usr/bin/env sh
secretsFile=$PROJECT_DIR/scripts/fabric.secrets
if [ ! -f $secretsFile ]; then
    echo "warning: '$secretsFile' not found"
    exit 0
fi

apiKey=$(sed -n '1p' < $secretsFile)
secretKey=$(sed -n '2p' < $secretsFile)

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :Fabric:APIKey $apiKey" $PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH

$PROJECT_DIR/Fabric.framework/run $apiKey $secretKey
```

Note: the `echo "warning: "` part will be detected by Xcode, and put into the build log as a yellow warning.

Finally, here's a pre-commit git hook to check for a 40-character hex string accidentally being added to the `Info.plist`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

files=$(ls */Info.plist)

git diff --cached --name-status | while read modificationtype thisfile; do
        if [ "$modificationtype" == 'D' ]; then continue; fi
        for file in $files
        do
            if [ ! "$thisfile" == "$file" ]; then continue; fi
            if egrep '[0-9a-fA-F]{40}' $file ; then
                echo "ERROR: API key in file: ${file}"
                exit 1
            fi  
        done
done || exit $?
```